# Adding fuelUX help

Tags: 7, javascript

I just started with Drupal 7 and trying to learn. I really like it so far. However I'm not sure how to add fuelUX. I linked all the relevant js and css files in my theme but for some reason it throws me errors (checked in the browser console). I know these arent Drupals fault per se but I just looking around to see if someone else sucessfully implemented fuelUX (http://exacttarget.github.com/fuelux/#wizard) and knows what I'm missing?

In my case I'm trying to get the "wizard" widget working. The error I get is "Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined" on both all.js which includes all widgets, and the specific wizard.js which I tried to add while problemshooting.

Any clues? =)

Comment: install Bootstrap theme for starters.. http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap

Hint: you will need jQuery update dev version

Comment: why don't you use a ctools (modal) wizard, and theme it  .. ?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you may not have an AMD loader on the page so please try using the following file:

http://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/loader.min.js

This contains all of the JavaScript for Bootstrap and Fuel UX, with no dependency on an AMD loader. In case you haven't heard of AMD, here's some info:

https://gist.github.com/4686136

http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html